# Display Category Name of Current Post in WP Job Manager

Tags: plugins

I m trying to display Job Categories in WP Job Manager in the Single Post(Job Listing).

I tried below code but its displaying "Array".

```html
function get_the_job_category( $id = false ) {
  $categories = get_the_terms( $id, 'job_category' );
  if ( ! $categories || is_wp_error( $categories ) )
    $categories = array();

  $categories = array_values( $categories );

  foreach ( array_keys( $categories ) as $key ) {
    _make_cat_compat( $categories[$key] );
  }

  /**
   * Filters the array of categories to return for a post.
   *
   * @since 3.1.0
   * @since 4.4.0 Added `$id` parameter.
   *
   * @param array $categories An array of categories to return for the post.
   * @param int   $id         ID of the post.
   */
  return apply_filters( 'get_the_job_categories', $categories, $id );
}
```

How to display current job post category name?

Answer (score 1):

Somthing like this should solve your problem -

`<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'job_listing_category', '', ' / ' ); ?>`

You can read more about the_terms function here -

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_terms/

This should work for all taxonomies just change "job_listing_category".

Comment: Thanks for this - I had been trying to display categories in WP Job manager for ages!